# Conditional formating based date range in VB

Tags: vb.net

Have a column of dates which i need to compare to a specific time of the year, which establishes what calculation needs to be applyed then depending on the outcome apply conditional formating to highlight an adjcent cell, but need to remove the YY element as the contents spans multiple years.

if the date in A1 is between 1st Jan &  14th Mar use -8
if the date in A1 is between 15th Mar & 15th Oct use -17
if the date in A1 is between 16th Oct & 31st Dec use -8

Then deduct the above value from B1 to give a target

for each row (from 3 onwards)

if the target is < the value in n then change background orange in f

and repeat.

Any help would be greatly welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this Excel?  If so, then it has all kinds of conditional formatting stuff built right into the application; no programming needed.